# Fantasy story, beginning has old woman waiting in line to see someone important

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Maybe 20-30 years old. Paperback in English.

The first chapter (or maybe the preface, or intro, or maybe just a short story prequel) describes an old poor woman waiting in line with other people (most of them much better off than she is) to enter a castle gate (or maybe the inner keep, or seer's chamber.)

She has something of value she is bringing in order to gain an audience with the whoever everyone else is waiting in line to see. What she has is very small value compared to what most people are bringing.

I think she does let slip to someone what she is bringing, but won't show it to anyone.

It may have only been a few coins (life savings sort of thing,) but I have the recollection that it was something like the bones or ashes of an ancestor, or maybe a relic (finger bone of a saint.)

A few people are discussing what they are going to ask (or ask for) some maybe giving the woman a hard time (trying to make her give up her place in line) doubting what she has is real.

The guards at the entrance tell her, if what she has is not real the people she is seeing will know it and kick her out.

I don't think it was like she was going to a king to ask to have her family member released from dungeon type of request. It was more a request for a prophecy from a seer, magic to be used to find someone, or heal someone or something like that.

I think the person she was going to see was a woman (but not sure) but they treated her gracefully (i.e. well above her station) having examined what she had, it was real, and were going to grant what she was there to ask or ask for.

I can remember nothing of the rest of the story. It is also possible this was only a short story prequel to a series (which might be why I cant remember the story.) So I am thinking a short story prequel is likely.